# Compare URL with if statement to redirect properly to new URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, response.redirect

I am redesigning a website and new website comes with URL routing feature and some old url will need to be changed. But i want to properly redirect user with old url to new url of the website.

Old url     `http://www.abc.com/about`
New URL     `http://www.abc.com/about-us`

so thought of doing it in global.asx file with following piece of code.

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("http://www.abc.com/about"))
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.abc.com/about-us");
}
```

But this will trigger code execution for all URL mentioned below

```
http://www.abc.com/about
http://www.abc.com/about-us
http://www.abc.com/about-us/history
http://www.abc.com/about-us/vision
```

What is the better way of comparing a URL should i use a simple old school `if ( A == B)` or is their a better way of doing it

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Equals("http://www.abc.com/about")
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.abc.com/about-us");
}
```

OR Use this

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower()=="http://www.abc.com/about")
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.abc.com/about-us");
}
```

Regex can also be used but i am not good with and would about it unless i am not absolutely sure.

What are recommendation in this case

**UPDATE**: Decide to do it this way

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Equals("http://www.abc.com/about") || (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Equals("http://www.abc.com/about/")
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.abc.com/about-us");
}
```

Comment: Rather than using this i suggest you to write rewrite rules in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

**Try checking the response status code as well before redirecting:-**

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower()=="http://www.abc.com/about" 
&& HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode!=301)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 301;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.abc.com/about-us");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do the following:

```
if(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().EndsWith("abc.com/about"))
{
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.abc.com/about-us");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the end user can enter "abc.com/about" or "www.abc.com/about"

try this :

```
    if (Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("abc.com/about"))
        Response.Redirect("http://www.abc.com/about-us");
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you meant  `abc.com/about` OR `abc.com/about/` I have already done that & decide to do it as updated in my Question